# How can I search from two fields in a select2 dropdown

Tags: php, jquery-select2

I have just started using select2 and it is working fine when I fill the selections up with two fields using:

```
    function formatemp(item) { return  item.empnum + " : " + item.empname; }

$("#empsDropDown").select2({
     data:{ results: <?PHP echo json_encode($employees);?>, text: 'empname'},
     placeholder: " <?PHP echo lang("All");?> ",
     minimumInputLength: 2,
     allowClear: true,
     id: function(obj) {return obj.empnum;  },
     formatResult: formatemp,
     formatSelection: formatemp
 });
```

It displays in the format

001 : Bloggs

The search works using the

```
text: 'empname'
```

bit. so it only searches on the name. If you type 'B' in the search box, it will filter and find Bloggs etc. However if you type '0' in the search box it will return no results.

Is there anyway to get it to search both fields (empname and empnum)?

I am new to select2 so I'm hoping this is something obvious that I havent tried yet.

I have tried 
    `text: 'empname' + 'empnum'` and `text: 'empname', text: 'empnum'`

amongst other things and I have searched the docs and on this site but I can only seem to get it  to search on either one or the other, not both. I have also tried a custom matcher but that didn't seem to fit the purpose either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution by brute force. I am open to hearing any better solutions if anyone has any.

```
 function formatemp(item) { return  item.empnum + " : " + item.empname; }

    $("#empsDropDown").select2({
         data:{ results: <?PHP echo json_encode($employees);?>, text: formatemp},
         placeholder: " <?PHP echo lang("All");?> ",
         minimumInputLength: 2,
         allowClear: true,
         id: function(obj) {return obj.empnum;  },
         formatResult: formatemp,
         formatSelection: formatemp
     });
```

I just replaced `text: 'empname'` with `text: formatemp` the formatter function  that I was using to populate the list with. I never expected it to work but it did, really well.